# Why is $1 + 1 = 0$ in $\{0, 1\}$ (binary field) and not 1 or 2?

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, finite-rings

Stuck on the simplest case in my foray into fields...

I know there is a really similar question out there, but I can't find any contradiction with the field axioms if 1 + 1 = 1 instead of 0.

Can someone explicitly show me the logic behind why 1 + 1 = 0 over the binary field and not 1 or 2?

Comment: Which element of {0,1} is "2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well 2=0 in the binary field. Also, a field is an (abelian) group under addition so it satisfies cancellation: $a+b = a+c \Leftrightarrow b =c$. Since $0$ is stipulated to be the additive identity we have

$$1 + 1 = 1 = 1+0 \Leftrightarrow 1= 0$$

But we know $1 \neq 0$ , so $1 + 1 \neq 1$ in any field. This is a general application of the fact that in any group

$$a^2 = a \Leftrightarrow a = e$$.

Comment: Hi, could you clarify your first assertion? Intuitively, 2 = 0 in the binary field, but how would you prove that?

Comment: It's hard to say because it varies depending on how you defined the binary field. If you just said "it's the integers mod $2$" then you don't prove it, it just comes from the definition. If you say "it's composed of two elements, $\{0,1\}$ former additive identity, latter multiplicative identity, then you use what I just said to see the only option is $1 + 1 = 0$, and two is just a wierd symbol that means $1+ 1$.

Comment: Thanks, and do you know if there is a quick way to determine the result of addition over a field if instead of (0,1) we have (0, 1, 2), how do we decide if 2 + 2 = 0 or 2 + 2 = 1

Comment: Actually a really intuitive way is to picture these numbers in a cyclic arrangement. It is almost as if i'm doing operation on the indices instead of the actual numbers. Reminds me of pointers in programming. There is a lot left to learn...

Comment: The basic idea is that integers mod $p$ is always a field. You can check that the first integer for which $1 + 1 + ... + 1 $ added $n$ many times is $0$ is always prime in a field (if it happens). And you can check that this is also how many times any other non-zero number needs to be added to itself to be zero. Additionally, if this holds, the field can be seen as a vector space over the integers mod $p$ so it has $p^k$ elements for some $k$. Thus your above field cannot be "binary" as it has 3 elements.

Answer (score 1):

What's the additive inverse of $1$ if $1+1=1$?

The field axioms unambiguously decide what $+$ and $\cdot$ are for $\mathbb{F}_2$, and the above counter-question should give you an idea why.